# How do I extract the mean from columns in a set of .csv files and create a new data frame with the results?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a set of csv files showing monthly climate data for a range of different species. There are millions of observations in each file.

Is there a way to find the means for each month (column) in the individual files and create a new dataframe where the means from each original file is a single row and the rowname is the original file name?

I'm a bit of a newbie with R and just need help..

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a lot of information about your data, I am not quite sure if this really answers your question. If it doesn't, please try to elaborate on your problem by helping us understand your data structure.

```
#create dummy datasets with one column; "climatedata" as the column which should be averaged
month1 <- data.frame(climatedata = rnorm(100, mean=10))
month2 <- data.frame(climatedata = rnorm(100, mean=20))
month3 <- data.frame(climatedata = rnorm(100, mean=30))

#This step is necessary for printing the names of the dataframes in the new dataframe
comment(month1) <- "month1"
comment(month2) <- "month2"
comment(month3) <- "month3"

#save your datasets in a list
months = list(month1, month2, month3)

#create an empty dataframe  
newdf = data.frame(filename = character(), climatedata_mean = numeric())

#loop over your dataframes saved in the list "months"
for (i in months) {
  mean <- mean(i$climatedata) #create the mean of the column climatedata
  month <- comment(i) #extract the comment for the specific dataframe   
  newrow <- c(month, mean) #connect new entries in one vector
  newdf[nrow(newdf) + 1,] <- newrow #add the vector in a new line of the dataframe
  }
```

This seems to work for me. The mean of the column climatedata from each data frame, together with the name of the respective data frame is displayed in the new data frame newdf.

Hope this could help!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying so quickly! My .csv files each have 12 columns (one column for each month of the year). I think I can adapt the code you provided to accommodate this. Thank you so much for the help. I'll update with whether I can work it out and I will try to be more clear in future questions.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy to help if you have any further questions.